# using node passport.js for multiple websites

Tags: javascript, angularjs, node.js, angular-ui-router, passport.js

I am writing a node.js server to act as a REST server proxy for another server. Basically, it is going to allow multiple websites to authenticate, and provide a REST api for them to use.

I am going to use passport.js.

Below is the relevant section from the tutorial that I have a question about:

```
app.post('/login',
        passport.authenticate('local', { successRedirect: '/',
                                        failureRedirect: '/login'
                                        })
);
```

Is there a way to redirect to the website's root directory? The website doesn't have the same URL as the node server, so how do I tell it to redirect to the website's root directory? Or do I have to implement that logic in the website's UI Router (I am using angularJS for the framework in each of the websites), and to just check for a returned user object?

Do I also handle session expiry in the website's UI Router as well?

If I do that, how can I invalidate the session from the server side?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's break this down:

```
    how can I invalidate the session from the server side?
```

Use [redis-sessions](https://www.npmjs.org/package/redis-sessions) for this. The whole control flow is to store the session id and a time stamp inside redis. You can then flush redis at every n minutes to invalidate those sessions and then have your server check against redis to ensure the current session isn't expired. That's a high level description, here is a tutorial on saving [PHP sessions in Redis](http://www.sitepoint.com/saving-php-sessions-in-redis/), the same logic will map over for your node.js application.

```
   Is there a way to redirect to the website's root directory?
```

The following way is usually how I handle redirects:

```
    response.writeHead(200, {
       'Location': 'targetwebsite.com/index.html'

    });
    response.end();
```

Please let me know if you have any questions!

Comment: Hi, thanks for the answer. So regarding the redirect, I will be having multiple websites use the same node js server, so I cannot hardcode the website's URL. Is there another way to redirect to the login request's website's root directory?

Comment: hey, you could either have a dictionary of <website, website root url> or have the request containing the URL to redirect to. I would go with the first approach. Please let me know if you have any questions!

Comment: hi, I've been looking into redis-sessions. Do you know what the difference between it and redis-connect is? Does it come with its own redis server?

Comment: Hey, to be honest, I haven't explictly used connect-redis for session based apps, but the documentation does state that it does not come with a redis server, it just provides the connectivity layer for your node app to connect to redis. The algorithm to implement sessions is pretty straight forward though and goes like this: give each session a UUID and then place that UUID inside redis (have your redis as a whitelist for active sessions), every 15 minutes flush redis, then everytime a session requests something, check against that whitelist if the session is in there.

Comment: There's a bit more that goes into defining the entry point (as to when to initially put the session into redis) but except for that, the above methodology is essentially how the algorithm works! Please let me know if you have any questions!